# how to get a href tag from user defined tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, goose

can some please help me to get all href tags from 
https://www.cnoocltd.com/col/col32091/index.html

i load this url to goose and get html content to Beautifulsoup.
checked the html tag, foundall a href tags are in 'datastore' which is a custom tag. how can we extract the hrefs by beautifulsoup

```
article = g.extract(url='https://www.cnoocltd.com/col/col32091/index.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(article.raw_html, "lxml")
a = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"Introduction"})
for l in a:
    #print(l.findAll('option'))
    if l.find('div'):
        b =l.find('div').find('script')
        custom_values = []
        b.findAll(lambda tag:[custom_values.append(a[1]) for a in tag.attrs if a[0].startswith('a href')])
        print(custom_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

The links are encoded inside other `<script>` tag. First we locate the `<script>` tag with links, and then load the content of the tag as other BeautifulSoup object:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cnoocltd.com/col/col32091/index.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup( soup.select_one('.Introduction script').text, 'lxml' )

for tag in soup2.select('[href]'):
    print('{: <40}{}'.format( tag['href'], tag.text) )
```

Prints:

```
/art/2019/7/10/art_32091_15297761.html  CNOOC China Limited Signs Cooperation Framework Agreement with Sinopec Corp.
/art/2019/6/7/art_32091_15297108.html   CNOOC Limited entered into a Share Purchase Agreement for the Acquisition of 10% equity interest in Arctic LNG 2 LLC
/art/2019/5/23/art_32091_15296778.html  CNOOC Limited Announces Appomattox Field Commence Production
/art/2019/4/25/art_32091_15296251.html  CNOOC Limited Signed a Heads of Agreement with JSC Novatek for the Arctic LNG 2 Project
/art/2019/4/25/art_32091_15296244.html  CNOOC Limited Announces Key Operational Statistics for Q1 2019
/art/2019/4/24/art_32091_15296212.html  CNOOC China Limited Signs a Petroleum Contract with PetroChina
/art/2019/4/23/art_32091_15296172.html  CNOOC Limited Filed 2018 Annual Report on Form 20-F
/art/2019/4/12/art_32091_15295362.html  CNOOC Signs a PSC with Smart Oil
/art/2019/3/21/art_32091_15292499.html  Reserves and Production Steadily Expanded Net Profit Significantly Increased
/art/2019/1/29/art_32091_15284836.html  CNOOC Limited Announced a New Discovery in UK North Sea
/art/2019/1/23/art_32091_15284095.html  CNOOC Limited Announces its 2019 Business Strategy and Development Plan
/art/2019/1/16/art_32091_15283206.html  CNOOC Limited Announces Huizhou 32-5 Oilfield Comprehensive Adjustment/Huizhou 33-1 Oilfield Joint Development Project Commences Production
/art/2019/1/2/art_32091_15272711.html   CNOOC Limited Announces Egina Field Commenced Production
```

---

EDIT: For getting `<option>` values:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cnoocltd.com/col/col32091/index.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for option in soup.select('.Introduction option[value]'):
    print(option['value'])
```

Prints:

```
/col/col32091/index.html
/col/col32091/index.html
/col/col47345/index.html
/col/col44151/index.html
/col/col28131/index.html
/col/col14041/index.html
/col/col8341/index.html
/col/col8351/index.html
/col/col8361/index.html
/col/col8371/index.html
/col/col8381/index.html
/col/col8391/index.html
/col/col8401/index.html
/col/col8411/index.html
/col/col8421/index.html
/col/col8431/index.html
/col/col8441/index.html
/col/col8451/index.html
/col/col8461/index.html
/col/col8471/index.html
```

Comment: thank you Kesely, one more question
how can i get option values in same Introduction